# In Browser Automation Studio how to create a bot that copies text from an Excel file and pastes it into a field on a website using Javascript?

Tags: automation, copy, bots, task, paste

I use Browser Automation Studio version 26.1.1 to automate my tasks.

I've already created a project, added actions and everything works fine. I added the "Read cell" action to make the bot copy some text that is in sheet 3 of cell C4 of my Excel file and paste it into the field of a website. I clicked on the field where the bot should paste the text. I clicked the "Run Javascript on Element" action and added the following code:

```
// Select the field where you want to paste the text
var element = document.querySelector(">CSS> :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(2) > input");

// Paste the text into the field
element.value = Engine.GetClipboardText("VARTRTITLEPAGE");
```

I want the robot to copy the text from my Excel file and paste it into the field on my website. If I run the script, the Browser Automation Studio console displays the following information:

> [989688634] [13:19:54] Topic #1: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '>CSS> :nth -child(2) > :nth-child(1 ) > :nth -child(2) > input' is not a valid selector.

Can you help me ?